# PnP SharePoint Framework npm install issues

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp, error-handling, npm

My organization is starting to really get into SharePoint development and I'm currently working on several projects related to SharePoint.

I've really been getting into the SharePoint Framework Development and the PnP program. I've gone thru several of the SharePoint Framework tutorials and have successfully created several web parts and deployed them to my M365 Dev environment.

There are some samples though on the PnP Sample page that I would like to try to setup in my environment but I am having issues with the **npm install** command. I've tried it on some of the sample and tutorials, but it is constantly failing (even on the ones in the tutorial folder).

I've gone thru and used nvm to install the different node.js versions associated with the samples but it is always failing no matter the node.js version.

I was hoping to get some guidance on how to work around this issue.

Update: Here are some of the error messages I am getting.

This morning when I try to use npm install I get this error: npm ERR! nested aliases not supported

Here is a copy of the attempts I tried last night:

44396 warn notsup Unsupported engine for karma@0.13.22: wanted: {"node":"0.10 || 0.12 || 4 || 5"} (current: {"node":"14.20.0","npm":"6.14.17"})
44397 warn notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: karma@0.13.22
44398 verbose notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: karma@0.13.22
44398 verbose notsup Required: {"node":"0.10 || 0.12 || 4 || 5"}
44398 verbose notsup Actual:   {"npm":"6.14.17","node":"14.20.0"}
44399 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
44400 warn notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
44401 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid OS:    darwin
44401 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid Arch:  any
44401 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual OS:   win32
44401 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual Arch: x64
44402 warn notsup Unsupported engine for got@5.7.1: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.0 <7"} (current: {"node":"14.20.0","npm":"6.14.17"})
44403 warn notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: got@5.7.1
44404 verbose notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: got@5.7.1
44404 verbose notsup Required: {"node":">=0.10.0 <7"}
44404 verbose notsup Actual:   {"npm":"6.14.17","node":"14.20.0"}
44405 verbose stack Error: node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
44405 verbose stack Exit status 1
44405 verbose stack     at EventEmitter. (C:\Users\johne\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.20.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
44405 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:400:28)
44405 verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (C:\Users\johne\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.20.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
44405 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
44405 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1088:16)
44405 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:296:5)
44406 verbose pkgid node-sass@3.13.1
44407 verbose cwd G:\YoProjects\SharePoint\sp-dev-fx-webparts\tutorials\tutorial-getting-started\jquery-webpart
44408 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.22000
44409 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "i"
44410 verbose node v14.20.0
44411 verbose npm  v6.14.17
44412 error code ELIFECYCLE
44413 error errno 1
44414 error node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
44414 error Exit status 1
44415 error Failed at the node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall script.
44415 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
44416 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Comment: What is the error message? Try to use same SPFx/Node.js/npm/yo/gulp versions as of the sample given in PnP repository. Also, check [compatibility matrix](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/compatibility) for SPFx.

Comment: Please share the error message

Comment: To help you better, can you share more information and the error message on this issue?

Comment: I updated the post with some of the error messages.

Comment: @GaneshSanap Thanks for that matrix, that does help a lot!

Comment: Is it working for you now or still facing the issue even after using correct versions?

Comment: @GaneshSanap, sort of. Your comment helped me find the Troubleshooting page and finding the cli commands for setting up your workspace to be compatible. Most of the commands are outdated but the CLI documentation has the updated commands.

I'm running thru the 'Upgrade the sample' instructions right now and it is having me install/update a bunch of things.

https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-webparts/gettingstarted/troubleshooting/

Comment: @GaneshSanap I got thru most of the errors, but now I'm getting the following error with tslint:
[12:11:49] Starting subtask 'lint'...
[12:11:49] Error - 'lint' sub task errored after 98 ms 
 TSLint is not supported for rush-stack-compiler-4.X packages.

I added build.tslintCmd.enabled = false; into the gulpfile.js file and I'm not able to resolve the error yet.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it up and running. Figuring out the items that I needed to install/set for compatibility was fun. For the 'lint' error I had to download and install eslint (https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint) and run it while I bundled and packaged the solution. Thanks all for your help!